# Why is this code block not rendered?

Tags: support, bug, markdown-rendering

I found some unusual event while posting a question on stackoverflow.com.
May be that is a bug or something, that I want your attention on.

Here is the screen shot of it.
[image]

Comment: Looks like you should add a newline between the text and the code block.

Answer (score 12):

This is not a bug with the preview, it's a bug with your formatting.

A code block must be separated with blank lines before and after it. Your code block is properly indented, but there is no blank line between it and your body text in the previous paragraph.

The code block doesn't appear as text because it contains angle brackets, which look like invalid HTML and are therefore stripped out by the Markdown parser.

Comment: But still if code block is behave like a text then the code must appears in the preview (as a text) right ?

Comment: Fair question. Updated answer with the response.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that image, I suppose the problem is that the code block is not shown.
The system thinks of the code block as part of the text, and renders it as HTML. It thinks of the indentation as part of the text, too.

You indented it properly, but you should also add a newline before the code. Then the system will recognize it as a code block.

As Cody Gray points out in [their answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341012/why-is-this-code-block-not-rendered/341013#341013), the system does not consider it valid HTML, so it is stripped out entirely - including any text between your XAML tags.